# How to install packages for different versions of Python?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have several versions of python installed:

```
root@10:~/projects/cobbler# whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python2.6-config /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.6 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python /etc/python2.6 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.1 /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.7 /usr/lib64/python3.1 /usr/lib64/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.6 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.6 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
root@10:~/projects/cobbler# /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.6.5
root@10:~/projects/cobbler# /usr/bin/python2.7 --version
Python 2.7.4
root@10:~/projects/cobbler#
```

And then when I need a package, `pip` installs it to the 2.6 version:

```
root@10:~/projects/cobbler# python setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import glob, os, sys, time, yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
root@10:~/projects/cobbler# pip install pyyaml
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
Installing collected packages: pyyaml
Successfully installed pyyaml
```

I come from ruby background. What is the way to install python packages for a specific python version?

And using virtualenv does not appear to be working for installing a package?

```
(virt_env_2.7.5)root@10:~/virt_env_2.7.5# python /root/projects/cobbler/setup.py build
running build
running build_py
building koan man page.
sh: cannot create ./docs/koan.1.gz: Directory nonexistent
Can't open ./docs/koan.pod: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/pod2man line 59
Creation of koan manpage failed.
```

Comment: **please** don't do all your work as root! Imagine mistyping `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/notneededanymore` as `rm -rf / usr/local/lib/notneededanymore`. You just completely hosed your system.

Comment: @MattDMo, thanks for the advice. I only recently switched from sudoing everything to actually using root. Imagine mistyping `sudo rm -rf / something-rather`, is that any better? That said, your advice is perfectly good, and most people should not use the root account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each installation of python should have its own installation of `pip`. Then you
can install packages for a particular version of python by calling the right
`pip`.

You might already have `pip` installed for each version of python. For
example, look in your virtualenv's `bin` directory (the same one that contains
the `activate` script.)

If not, [here are
instructions](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) on how to
install `pip`. Be sure to provide a full path to the python executable when you
run `/path/to/python get-pip.py`. The installation of python whose executable you specify is the installation that that `pip` will affect when installing packages.